# How to attach WSL image on external drive to fresh Windows install?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently did a fresh install of Windows 11 (I had windows 10 before that). I also was using WSL2 for work and `.vhdx` image was on external drive (what I mean by it is that the image is simply on another SSD within my desktop PC). How can I connect that vhdx image to my Windows 11 machine to be able to use it again?

I terminated and unregistered fresh `Ubuntu` image that was mounted to disk C and tried the following command I found:

```
wsl --import Ubuntu-20.04 U:\Ubuntu-20.04 U:\Ubuntu-20.04\ext4.vhdx --vhd
```

But it didn't work and threw an error

> Error code: Wsl/WSL_E_DEFAULT_DISTRO_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 0):

#### Replication

I replicated your situation and got an error, altough not the one you report. Can you do also `wsl --list --all` so we can see what distros you have, and which one is the default?

#### The error I got

```
wsl --import <Distro> <InstallLocation> <FileName> [Options]
```

When you import a distro, WSL copies the drive to `InstallLocation/ext4.vhdx`. It seems that your exitsing vhdx may be colliding with the one generated by WSL. You can instead use:

```
wsl --import-in-place <Distro> <FileName>
```

so as to use the file you already have. Alternatively you can choose a diferent install location.